# VBA エクセルのデータベース化

Tags: database, excel, vba

Excelにおいて一列目に日付別に、一行目にID別に整理されたデータがあります。
これデータベースとして使えるように整理したいのですが、Excelで使えるVBAのコードがあれば教えてください。Transposeで出来るかと思ったのですが。

オリジナルデータ

```
 2016   2015   2014....        
A Suzuki Yamada Tanaka 
B Takai  Kuroi  Nakano
C Tako   Yano    Sano
```

データベース化

```
A 2016 Suzuki
A 2015 Yamada
A 2014 Tanaka
B 2016 Takai
B 2015 Kuroi
.
.
.
.
C 2014 Sano
```

初心者ですが、コードの意味は自身で調べようと思います。

Comment: VBAでコードを書いた経験はあるのですか？　どこで、躓いているのですか？

Comment: 自身で1から書くのはこれが初めてです。対象範囲を選んで変数宣言までは出来ていますが、どのfunctionで自分のやりたいことが出来るのかがわ駆らない状態です

Comment: FWIW: 当該処理は、一般的には正規化、と呼ばれます。

Answer (score 1):

ざくっとですが、以下のような感じです。
エクセルに二つシートを作成して、1枚目にデータを入力してください。
2枚目に結果が出力されます。

```
Sub convert()
Dim inputWS As Worksheet
Dim outputWS As Worksheet

Dim year As String
Dim id As String
Dim name As String

Dim num As Integer

Set inputWS = Sheets(1)
Set outputWS = Sheets(2)

num = 1

For Row = 2 To 4
    For col = 2 To 4

        year = inputWS.Cells(1, col).Value
        id = inputWS.Cells(Row, 1).Value
        name = inputWS.Cells(Row, col).Value

        outputWS.Cells(num, 1).Value = id
        outputWS.Cells(num, 2).Value = year
        outputWS.Cells(num, 3).Value = name

        num = num + 1
    Next col
Next Row

End Sub
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。RowとColをForではさむんですね。少し修正して使用しました。今後もこれをベースに使わせていただきます